# Im trying to make a sider connected to a variable "Cannot invoke initializer for type "Int" with an argument list of type '(_)' "

Tags: swift

I am making an app for a school project which is a finger painter where the user can draw with their finger. I am making a slider that changes the size of their line and then using that value as the size. However, I have come across the error "Cannot invoke initializer for type "Int" with an argument list of type '(_)' ". I have researched but have not been able to find a solution. The error occurs on the line that with changeSize:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var canvas: UIImageView!
var start: CGPoint?
var size: Int = 5
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func clearImage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    canvas.image = nil
}

@IBAction func changeSize(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var size = Int(sender.value)
}
```

Comment: i think your issue is the redeclaration of size

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Beran your are trying to get the value from UIBarButtonItem.not UISlider

```
@IBAction func changeSize(_ sender: UISlider) {
    var size = Int(sender.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. in changeSize func you have parameter sender of UIBarButtonItem type instead of UISlider.
2. In this method you create a new variable "size" which was never used. I think, you should not create a new var, instead of this just to use existed "size" property.

`@IBAction func changeSize(_ sender: UISlider) {
    size = Int(sender.value)
}`